# How to fix dynamic added elements aren't dragging or sorting jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one button, and when i click it it adds elements that are with same class, for example my class is **image_class**, the default added elements are being dragged, but when i add new element with the class i can't drag it or sort it.How can i fix that ?I want when dynamically added element shows up to be dragged or sorted .There is no problem with the default ones.

I'm using jquery ui

Comment: Sample code? Libraries used? ANYTHING?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's one way of doing it (and since I have no idea what your button code does...)

http://jsfiddle.net/TrowthePlow/qZz5j/

Comment: button is just adding element with class that is being dragged

Comment: @averbaher: so my code would work then? If not, POST THE CODE that you use to 'add the element'

Answer (score 0):

By default, events are added at runtime and not bound to elements created after the point of binding, even when they have the same selector.

To make sure that events are bound to items with the same selector dynamically, make sure you use the [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to bind your events.

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```

Comment: sorry it's jquery ui not a regular one